# I want to display Employee name with displaying multiple BankaccountNames in java

Tags: java

1. create `class Employee`
   Attributes: `name` and `id`

create

```
private ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccountList;
```

2. create `class BankAccount`
   a. like citi bank,canara bank etc

attributes:

```
accountType: saving
accountName: citi/sbi
accountNo:12345

private Employee accountHolder;
```

output:

```
Name: john
bank accounts:1. citi bank
              2. sbi 
              3. canara bank
```

like it needs to display

Comment: Sounds like an interesting homework assignment. Can you share the code you've attempted so far, as explained at [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it you want to print out the information about an `Employee`.

```
public void printEmployee(Employee1 employee)
{
   System.out.println("Name:" + employee.getName());

   ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts = employee.getBankAccountList();
   
   System.out.println("Bank Accounts:");
   for(BankAccount ba : bankAccounts)
   {
       System.out.println(ba.getAccountNo + ". " + ba.getAccountName());
   }
}
```

Then you can use this in a loop to print the information of all `Employee1` in a list as you seem to want to do later on.

```
for(Employee1 employee : employeeList)
{
   printEmployee(employee);
}
```

However, I would suggest refactoring your code to begin with.

Changing names such as `Employee1` to `Employee`, removing unused variables such as `banklist` and changing all class attributes to `private` since you use `getters` and `setters` to access them.

Tidying up could make it easier to spot any mistakes in your code which will reduce headaches.

From where I was taught in university it is also preferable to have one `class` per file. In this case have one Employee.java file, one BankAccount.java file and one EmployeePrograms.java file, rather than having them all in just one file together. This could make life easier aswell.